# Integral inequality involving the biharmonic operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let M be a hyperbolic surface and let f be a real smooth function on M.

Considering a geometric inequality which I conjectured to be true for different reasons, I get after a lot of computations that the inequality is in fact equivalent to the following

$$ \int_{M}(f^2 - \frac{1}{4}\(Delta(f))^2)dM≤ \frac{1}{V}(\int_{M}fdM)^2 $$,

where dm is the volume form on M and $V=\int_{M}dM$.

Is this inequality correct or false ?

Comment: The laplacian term integrates to zero, so what you've written becomes a much simpler conjecture. Perhaps this question as is, is not appropriate for the site. 

Comment: I suspect the parentheses are in the wrong place. 

Comment: I apologize: the notation was unclear. Thank you.

Comment: It still can't be correct as written can be seen by scaling the metric $g\to \lambda g$ for $\lambda>>1$ and taking any non-zero function $f$ orthogonal to the constants.

Comment: But if you scale the metric, you change the curvature (by hyperbolic, I mean "constant curvature equal to -1").

Comment: Are you still sure in your question? Because the biharmonic operator is usually something else: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation

Comment: Yes, the OP is right. The Euler-Lagrange equation for the functional has the biharmonic operator as the top order term.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1974-80-05/S0002-9904-1974-13609-8/S0002-9904-1974-13609-8.pdf) of Randol which I found in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58591/lower-bound-on-the-first-eigenvalue-of-the-laplacian-of-a-riemann-surface-with-co) of BR.  Compact surfaces with metrics of constant curvature $-1$ may have first eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ as small as one likes.  An eigenfunction $\phi_1$ of this eigenvalue gives a counter-example to your claim